# Technical documentation of the IOTA protocol

Tags: documentation

To properly understand technology like this, I need to sit down and crunch the numbers, program it up, and learn from that.

I  can't find any technical, low-level documentation on the IOTA protocol.

One example is [Dom's gitbook](http://www.gitbook.com/book/domschiener/iota-guide) were some details are explained, but most is just references to functions of the API/Library - Not how a seed is used to create private keys and addresses, changing those trytes into numbers and then into the cryptographical world.

Does anyone have any links or PDFs, or do I have to take a deep dive into the source code?

Comment: at the current state of the system, deep diving into the source code of iota.lib.js and iri is indeed the most reliable source of information.

Comment: Yep, also discovered this. I would like to see technical specs. I would like to implement a flash channel client in Scala. At the moment the only option is to read the Javascript Code. Takes some time... and trying things out. Maybe we can start a github project for it. Discovering the protocol and writing specs for it.

Comment: One issue: Maybe they change the protocol dramatically. That means: You have to change also your implementation and specs. You see: At the moment the tangle is just Beta.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the most reliable documentation out there would be the [official IOTA documentation](https://iota.readme.io/v1.2.0/docs). However this may not be in enough detail, so the only thing to do, as suggested in the comments, would be to look through the s[ource code of the various libraries and packages](https://github.com/iotaledger)